# Maybe not public or not valid? Using Spring's Websocket and Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, spring-kafka

As I am trying to consume data from a topic (the topic name is based on user) and during runtime I am trying to consume message from the topic but I am getting the following error.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   Property or field 'consumerProperties' cannot be found on object of
>   type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
>   - maybe not public or not valid?

Here is my code

```
@Service
public class kafkaConsumerService {


    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

     KafkaConsumerProperties consumerProperties;

     @Autowired
    public kafkaConsumerService(KafkaConsumerProperties consumerProperties, SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
         this.consumerProperties=consumerProperties;
         this.template=template;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = {"#{consumerProperties.getTopic()}"})
    // @KafkaListener(topics="Chandan3706")
    public void consume(@Payload Message message) {
        System.out.println("from kafka topic::" + message);
        template.convertAndSend("/chat/getMessage", message);
    }

}
```

My KafkaConsumerProperties.class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="kafka.consumer")
public class KafkaConsumerProperties {

    private String bootStrap;
    private String group;
    private String topic;

    public String getBootStrap() {
        return bootStrap;
    }

    public void setBootStrap(String bootStrap) {
        this.bootStrap = bootStrap;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KafkaConsumerProperties [bootStrap=" + bootStrap + ", group=" + group + ", topic=" + topic + "]";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since you don’t provide any bean name for your `KafkaConsumerProperties` component, the default one is [de-capitalized class name](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-name-generator). That’s one.

The expression you use in the `@KafkaListener` is regular [bean definition phase expression](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based), therefore a root object is some `BeanExpressionContext` , but not your listener bean as you try to get access through the property.

Not sure if you need that `KafkaConsumerProperties` property in this listener, but expression must ask for the `kafkaConsumerProperties` bean:

```
@Service
public class kafkaConsumerService {


    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

     @Autowired
    public kafkaConsumerService(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
         this.template=template;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = {"#{kafkaConsumerProperties.topic}"})
    // @KafkaListener(topics="Chandan3706")
    public void consume(@Payload Message message) {
        System.out.println("from kafka topic::" + message);
        template.convertAndSend("/chat/getMessage", message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share some working code which can help me in this case.

Comment: Wait: I fully explained you what is wrong with your code and showed how to fix. Not sure what else you would like to hear from us. Nobody here is going to code for you. The Docs on the matter is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#kafka-listener-annotation

Comment: I wanted to have a better clarity of your answer as your reply is senseless and before jumping to any conclusion I wanted to be sure.... As In my case I have already created a bean for KafkaConsumerProperties class. And only the problem which I am facing is with the Spring Expressions language

Comment: OK. I added links to Docs whenever it is necessary to confirm my comments and added a fully modified your `kafkaConsumerService` class to show how that has to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me, notice to @DependsOn("KafkaConsumerProperties") and  @Component("KafkaConsumerProperties") annotations.

**KafkaConsumerService class:**

```
@Service
@DependsOn("KafkaConsumerProperties")
public class KafkaConsumerService {

   @KafkaListener(topics = "#{@KafkaConsumerProperties.getTopic()}")
   public void consume(@Payload Message message) {
       System.out.println("from kafka topic::" + message);
       template.convertAndSend("/chat/getMessage", message); 
   }
}
```

**KafkaConsumerProperties class:**

```
@Component("KafkaConsumerProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="kafka.consumer")
public class KafkaConsumerProperties {

   private String topic;

   public String getTopic() {
       return topic;
   }
}
```